# How do fuel cells work?

Tags: electrochemistry

I have been reading an introductory book on fuel cells, and it's indicated that SOFC need to be brought to $\pu{600\! -\! 1000 ^\circ C}$ to be more efficient.
So, my understanding is that if I want to have a working fuel cell, I would need to come up with a system that could "heat up" my fuel cell to $\pu{750 ^\circ C}$? 
Most of the articles I have been reading explain how fuels cells work, but what would be the actual set-up? I would have to put the fuel cell in some sort of oven? 
Thanks for your input!

Comment: There is no physical or chemical law that says all fuel cells work better at 600-100°C. For SOFC's that is generally true, but the actual optimal temperature is different for every model.

Comment: The actual setup is a well insulated fuel cell, a heat exchanger for fuel and exhaust gas/water, and an additional electrical heater for startup. Or so i would guess.